# Is it safe to move system applications like Preview in OS X?

Tags: macos

I'd like to move a bunch of applications from `/Applications/` to `/Applications/Preinstalled/` like Preview, Mail, etc.

OS X complains that I can't do this:

> “Preview” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by OS X.

I **can**, using `sudo mv`, but will it break things?

I want a nicely organized *Applications* stack in my dock, with folders for *Preinstalled*, *Development*, *Graphics*, etc.  Is there another way to accomplish what I'm after?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it.

1. Create an alias of the `.app` file – for example `iTunes.app` – by highlighting it and pressing <kbd>Cmd-L</kbd>. Then, move this alias to your desired folder and remove the "alias" part. Leave the original file where it is.
2. If you want to hide the original, open your Terminal.app, and enter this:

   ```
   sudo chflags hidden /Applications/iTunes.app
   ```

   This will hide the app. To unhide it:

   ```
   sudo chflags nohidden /Applications/iTunes.app
   ```

---

Instead of using aliases, you can also create a symlink in step 1. This has the same effect, but aliases "remember" their target files and you could theoretically move them around the drive. (But since we don't want that anyway, there's virtually no difference.)

```
ln -s /Applications/iTunes.app /Applications/somewhere-else/iTunes.app
```

Comment: Is *alias* just a symlink?

Comment: Found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28Mac_OS%29 -> no, it's more like a Windows `.lnk` shortcut but with more OS integration.  Still not very shell-friendly.  What do you think about using symlinks instead?

Comment: It's a little less shell-friendly but I don't know why one would need an `.app` package (or rather, the symlink to it) to be shell-friendly.